# Concating two arrays into one

Tags: javascript

I am looking to combine these two arrays into a single one.  I want any id information that is the same to be filtered so that it only appears once, making it a simple list of name, age, occupation, and address.

I have tried simply concating the info, using splice, using filter... but I just cant seem to get the right answer.

```
var a = [{
  id: 'aBcDeFgH',
  firstName: 'Juan',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: 32
 },
{
  id: 'zYxWvUt',
  firstName: 'Alex',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  age: 24
}]


var b = [{
  id: 'aBcDeFgH',
  occupation: 'architect',
  address: {
    street: '123 Main St',
    city: 'CityTown',
    Country: 'USA'
  }
},
{
  id: 'zYxWvUt',
  occupation: 'receptionist',
  address: {
    street: '555 Ocean Ave',
    city: 'Beach City',
    Country: 'USA'
  }
}]
```

I always end up with a single list after the concat, but I cant find out how to filter the same info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to merge each item of each array together - and that they're both in the same order, in which case you could do:

```
const newList = []

a.forEach((item, index) => {
  newList.push({
    ...item,
    ...b[index]
  })
})

console.log(newList)
```

Comment: This merge the items on the basis of their index not on the `id`

Comment: Which was stated so in the answer and not specified by OP.

Comment: OP said _"I am looking to combine these two arrays into a single one, **with the id information** that is the same filtered....."_

Answer (score 3):

You can make an object from first array `a` whole keys will be `id` of each object. Then use `map()` on `b` and return object having all props.

```js
var a = [{
  id: 'aBcDeFgH',
  firstName: 'Juan',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: 32
 },
{
  id: 'zYxWvUt',
  firstName: 'Alex',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  age: 24
}]


var b = [{
  id: 'aBcDeFgH',
  occupation: 'architect',
  address: {
    street: '123 Main St',
    city: 'CityTown',
    Country: 'USA'
  }
},
{
  id: 'zYxWvUt',
  occupation: 'receptionist',
  address: {
    street: '555 Ocean Ave',
    city: 'Beach City',
    Country: 'USA'
  }
}]

let obj = a.reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a.id] = a,ac),{});
let res = b.map(x => ({...x,...obj[x.id]}));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: @Daan Actually Stack snippets was not working so I can't test Now I updated check it please

Answer (score 1):

The following will reconstruct the array in the same order as `a` but the function doesn't depend on `b` being in the same order.

```js
var a = [{id:"aBcDeFgH",firstName:"Juan",lastName:"Doe",age:32},{id:"zYxWvUt",firstName:"Alex",lastName:"Smith",age:24}],
    b = [{id:"aBcDeFgH",occupation:"architect",address:{street:"123 Main St",city:"CityTown",Country:"USA"}},{id:"zYxWvUt",occupation:"receptionist",address:{street:"555 Ocean Ave",city:"Beach City",Country:"USA"}}];

let res = a.reduce((a,c) => {a.push({...c, ...b.find(v => v.id == c.id)}); return a;},[])

console.log(res)
```

And as a **more performant** solution, that instead of using `find` for every look-up uses a map-like object for our second array so we just have to insert from it for our result via O(1) look-ups.

So instead of O(n²) we now have O(n):

```js
var a = [{id:"aBcDeFgH",firstName:"Juan",lastName:"Doe",age:32},{id:"zYxWvUt",firstName:"Alex",lastName:"Smith",age:24}],
    b = [{id:"aBcDeFgH",occupation:"architect",address:{street:"123 Main St",city:"CityTown",Country:"USA"}},{id:"zYxWvUt",occupation:"receptionist",address:{street:"555 Ocean Ave",city:"Beach City",Country:"USA"}}];

let tmp = b.reduce((a,c) => {a[c.id] = c; return a},{}),
    res = a.reduce((a,c) => {a.push({...c, ...tmp[c.id]}); return a;},[]);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` is the key to compare,

```js
const concatListById = (base, target) => base.reduce((acc, c) => {
    const matched = target.find(e => e.id === c.id);
    let el = c;
    if (matched) el = { ...matched, ...c };
    acc.push(el);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(concatListById(a, b));
```

If there is an assumption that id sequence of each array is the same,

```js
const justMergeArray = (base, target) => 
  base.map((e, idx) => ({ ...e, ...target[idx] }));

console.log(justMergeArray(a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and compare if `id match` just push into same object and add this to an `array`

```js
var a = [{
    id: 'aBcDeFgH',
    firstName: 'Juan',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 32
  },
  {
    id: 'zYxWvUt',
    firstName: 'Alex',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    age: 24
  }
]


var b = [{
    id: 'aBcDeFgH',
    occupation: 'architect',
    address: {
      street: '123 Main St',
      city: 'CityTown',
      Country: 'USA'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'zYxWvUt',
    occupation: 'receptionist',
    address: {
      street: '555 Ocean Ave',
      city: 'Beach City',
      Country: 'USA'
    }
  }
]

const res = a.reduce((all, acc, index) => {
  if (acc.id === b[index].id) {
    all.push({
      ...acc,
      ...b[index]
    });
  }
  return all;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
 var a = [{
  id: 'aBcDeFgH',
  firstName: 'Juan',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: 32
 },
{
  id: 'zYxWvUt',
  firstName: 'Alex',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  age: 24
}]

var b = [{
  id: 'aBcDeFgH',
  occupation: 'architect',
  address: {
    street: '123 Main St',
    city: 'CityTown',
    Country: 'USA'
  }
},
{
  id: 'zYxWvUt',
  occupation: 'receptionist',
  address: {
    street: '555 Ocean Ave',
    city: 'Beach City',
    Country: 'USA'
  }
}];


const newA =   a.reduce((acc, ele) => (acc[ele.id] = ele, ele),{});
const result  = b.map(ele=> ({...newA[ele.id],...ele}));

console.log(result);
```